# How to cancel a drop action for jQuery droppable?

Tags: jquery-ui, droppable

I have a jQuery UI droppable which accepts draggables. I want to not allow the drop action if certain conditions are met.

How do I cancel the drop action and do a revert like action?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [`accept`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-accept) option on the droppable widget:

> All draggables that match the selector
>   will be accepted. If a function is
>   specified, the function will be called
>   for each draggable on the page (passed
>   as the first argument to the
>   function), to provide a custom filter.
>   The function should return true if the
>   draggable should be accepted.

combined with the [`revert`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert) option on draggable should get you what you need:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: function(el) {
        /* This is a filter function, you can perform logic here 
           depending on the element being filtered: */
        return el.hasClass('acceptable');
    }
});
```

Note that in this specific example, you could also write `accept: ".acceptable"`, which would make the droppable only accept elements with class `acceptable`.  So another option is when your custom event happens, just apply or remove the `acceptable` class as necessary.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/rUgJF/3/

The bottom has a link toggling "acceptability" on an off.